# position fixed (same effect as css) with Qt

Tags: css, qt, qwidget, qt-designer, qtextedit

### Question:

Like in `css`, is there an equivalent of `position: fixed;` in Qt ?

### Picture :

What I want is to move the second bubble (a subclassed QTextEdit) to the left when my main windows is resized. The second picture shows what I want to prevent.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the bubble? A `QWidget`? A `QGraphicsItem`? A frame in a `QTextDocument`?

Comment: it is a subclassed QTextEdit. I subclassed it just to change its style.

Comment: OK, so the entire bubble is one instance of `QTextEdit`?

Comment: exactly... That was just for its style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bubbles are an instances of `QWidget`, the simplest thing to do would be to put them into a layout and either left- or right-align them in the layout using `bool QLayout::setAlignment(QWidget * w, Qt::Alignment alignment)`.

You will need to limit the maximum width of the widgets to, say, 2/3 of the overall width of the yellow area, and this will have to be dynamically adjusted. You can do this by installing an event filter to catch `QResizeEvent` on the area, or implement `resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)` on the area's class.

Comment: it works great! But container (the yellow area here) must be set to align its elements vertically.